# JSoup / Selenium Web Driver missing content

Tags: html, selenium, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm trying to scrape information from this [page](https://www.reddit.com/r/RocketLeagueExchange/new/) using JSoup or Selenium Web Driver.
This is my Selenium implementation:

```
package reddit;

import java.util.logging.Level;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

public class Reddit {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF); 
    WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
    while(true){
        driver.get("https://www.reddit.com/r/RocketLeagueExchange/new/");
        WebElement post = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("p.title"));
        String platform = post.findElement(By.className("linkflairlabel")).getText();
        System.out.println("Platform:"+platform);
    }
}

}
```

The information I'm trying to get from the page is:

```
<span class="linkflairlabel" title="STEAM">STEAM</span>
```

That is the second child of:

```
<p class="title"><a class="title may-blank loggedin srTagged" data-event-action="title" href="/r/RocketLeagueExchange/comments/59nosd/pc_h_list_of_items_w_crates/" tabindex="1" rel="nofollow">[PC] [H] List of Items [W] Crates</a><span class="linkflairlabel" title="STEAM">STEAM</span> <span class="domain">(<a href="/r/RocketLeagueExchange/">self.RocketLeagueExchange</a>)</span></p>
```

The problem is that it won't fetch the text. I also tried using the `cssSelector()` but after a while it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find an element with xpath .//*[contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '),' linkflairlabel ')]
Driver info: driver.version: HtmlUnitDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitWebElement.findElementByXPath(HtmlUnitWebElement.java:725)
at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByClassName.findElement(By.java:392)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$5.call(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1725)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$5.call(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.implicitlyWaitFor(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1367)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElement(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1721)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitWebElement.findElement(HtmlUnitWebElement.java:655)
at reddit.Reddit.main(Reddit.java:21)
```

JSoup sometimes do the job sometimes won't.

I know this is a noob question but this is my first attempt, am I missing something?

EDIT:
when I run the program it warns:

```
ott 27, 2016 3:08:36 PM 

com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.InputElementFactory createElementNS
INFORMAZIONI: Bad input type: "email", creating a text input
ott 27, 2016 3:08:37 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
AVVERTENZA: CSS error: 'https://www.redditstatic.com/reddit.YBQ3OGUgns4.css' [1:95984] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>.)
ott 27, 2016 3:08:38 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
AVVERTENZA: CSS error: 'https://www.reddit.com/r/RocketLeagueExchange/new/' [1:1] Error in style sheet. (Invalid token "<". Was expecting one of: <EOF>, <S>, <IDENT>, "<!--", "-->", ".", ":", "*", "[", <HASH>, <IMPORT_SYM>, <PAGE_SYM>, <MEDIA_SYM>, <FONT_FACE_SYM>, <CHARSET_SYM>, <ATKEYWORD>.)
ott 27, 2016 3:08:38 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
AVVERTENZA: CSS error: 'https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/iInvQHcXVppWeQbAiLLVmDIZeWaC3nY_GVyunvQi0Hw.css' [1:57883] Error in simple selector. (Invalid token "{". Was expecting one of: <S>, <IDENT>, ".", ":", "*", "[", <HASH>.)
ott 27, 2016 3:08:38 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
AVVERTENZA: CSS warning: 'https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/iInvQHcXVppWeQbAiLLVmDIZeWaC3nY_GVyunvQi0Hw.css' [1:57883] Ignoring the whole rule.
```

EDIT2: I dumped the html source of the page and it contains the class/text I'm trying to get. So Selenium / Jsoup is missing that for some reason.

EDIT3:

Using:

```
(new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
                    public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
                        return d.findElement(By.cssSelector(locator)).getText().length() != 0;
                    }
                });
```

won't fix anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking deeply into your issue I see the problem, that you use `WebElement post = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("p.title"));` which will return the first element that fits the selector. It will not return all elements. It the first found element does not contain an inner element with class `linkflairlabel` your code will not work.

I see two solutions:

1)
Return all elements that fit the css selector `p.title` and loop over them to find the one(s) you are interested in. Use the `List<WebElement> posts = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("p.title"));` for that.

2)
Use a more specific css selector like this: `List<WebElement> linkFlairPosts = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("p.title span.linkflairlabel"));` This will get the relevant Elements in one go.

I would prefer using method 2 because it is cleaner and simpler.

Comment: Yeah, I know that my class returns only the first element and that's what I want. The HTML source contains the class I'm trying to get. If I "download" only the "p.title" element, are queries applied on that Element only?

Comment: Anyway, I tried both your solutions and finding elements by using xpath, nothing changed.

Comment: Did you look in the source as received through JSoup and Selenium, if the element is there?

Comment: Yes I dumped the HTML source, sometimes the text is there, sometimes don't. Looks like the page is filled by a javascript. I also tried re-getting the page if there's no text in that position using a while statement but it won't work...